# empty modules.dep after boot hang: what runs depmod during startup?

Tags: 14.04, boot, kernel, upstart

**tl;dr**: What runs "depmod" or otherwise messes with modules.dep during boot?

Full story:

Environment: notebook with radeon videocard, fglrx drivers. Kernel 3.13.0-87, ubuntu 14.04.4, upstart (not systemd).

Sometimes (infrequenty) notebook **hangs** during boot (seemingly when videocard is initialized,  there is fglrx "failed to initialize..." message on the last line of the log) and needs 5-second power button press. **But this is not the problem** I am trying to solve.

Sometimes after that system can no longer boot because it cannot mount /boot/efi, seemingly due to the lack of kernel module.

What really happens is that **modules.dep and modules.dep.bin at this point are empty (size=0)** and so no kernel modules can be loaded. Running "depmod" from Recovery shell fixes this.

I think that something runs depmod during startup, and when hang occurs modules.dep is being written to. On restart, fsck causes modules.dep to become empty, and the rest is history.

Question is: what runs depmod during boot?

I did `grep -r -l -E '(depmod|modules.dep)' /etc` and found nothing.

Any hints or ideas?